# Subplot with axis square

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use `subplot` with square axis but I failed, Below part of my code. I got `Fig` that has two plots but each one has different size

```
for i=1:N
figure
subplot (2,1,1);
plot (r(i,:),p(i,:));                                 
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:0.5:4)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:0.15:0.2)
axis square
xlim([0 4]);
ylim([-1 0.2]);
subplot (2,1,2);
[r,y]= meshgrid(linspace(0,4),linspace(0,4));
U =eval(U1);
[~,h] = contour(r,y,U,[0.001 0.01 0.05 0.08 0.1  0.2 0.25 0.3 0.4]);
set(h,'ShowText','on','TextStep',get(h,'LevelStep')*2)
colormap cool
grid on
axis square
hold on
xlim([0 4]);
ylim([0 4]);
plot (R,Y,'*r');                                       
hold off
daspect([1 1 1]);
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `axis square` *after* changing the x and y limits of the axes after all plotting is done. If you change the xlims and ylims *after* calling `axis square` MATLAB will forget that you wanted it to be square. This is because there is no property of the `axes` that indicates that you want a square matrix, it's simply computed when you call `axes square` based upon the current xlims and ylims and the data aspect ratio.

```
subplot (2,1,1);
plot (r(i,:),p(i,:));                                 
grid on
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:0.5:4)
set(gca, 'YTick', -1:0.15:0.2)

%// Do not call axis square here
xlim([0 4]);
ylim([-1 0.2]);

%// Call axis square here after you change the x/y limits
axis square
```

Comment: Thanks, Looks fine now